# Angular + Node + Universal remove # with working refresh

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-universal

I am using Angular 13 + Angular Universal + Node.js.
I have deployed app on server, but I have big problem with removing # from URL.

I have built app using

```
npm run build:ssr
```

And I am serving it using node.js app on my server using :

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/app-name/browser'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname)));
```

When I use HashLocationStrategy, then everything works fine. Problem appears when I am trying to remove hash from link.

I changed it to PathLocationStrategy and I am getting error 404 on refresh on other path than '/'.

I was trying to add different routes in node.js file to sendFile (f.e.)

```
app.get('/subpage', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname)));
```

But it didn't worked for me.
I was also trying to overwite # with node.js, but as it comes from angular app it's impossible to do it from node.js code.

My files :
app.server.module.ts

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { ServerModule } from '@angular/platform-server';
    
    import { AppModule } from './app.module';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import {UniversalInterceptor} from './universal-interceptor.service';
    import {HTTP_INTERCEPTORS} from '@angular/common/http';
    import {NgxSsrTimeoutModule} from '@ngx-ssr/timeout';
    
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        AppModule,
        ServerModule,
        NgxSsrTimeoutModule.forRoot({ timeout: 5000 }),
      ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
          useClass: UniversalInterceptor,
          multi: true,
        }
      ],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    })
    export class AppServerModule {}
```

server.ts

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

import {ngExpressEngine} from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import {join} from 'path';

import {AppServerModule} from './src/main.server';
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';
import {existsSync} from 'fs';

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/app-name/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => {
    res.status(404).send('data requests are not yet supported');
  });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, {req, providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl}]});
  });

  return server;
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env['PORT'] || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

How to to deploy app without '#' in url with working refresh?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I finally found solution for this. My problem was, that I needed to give absolute path to my index.html file for all angular routes. So finally i changed

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname)));
```

to

```
app.get('/**', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/app-name/browser/index.html'))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

app.get('*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname)));

put it near the end middleware chain

Comment: You mean to put it at end of index.js file? I have it already like this and it still doesn't works

Comment: change it from / to *

Comment: It doesn't help for me. I still have same error. I am starting to suspect that server.ts should be changed. Otherwise I have no idea how can I resolve problem.